# What would be time complexity of below code that uses Python dictionary and Count function?

Tags: python, loops, count, time-complexity

I'm new at figuring out time complexities and it's the area where I have the most trouble. The below code is simple but I'm trying to pin down the complexity for it. Can somebody help and elaborate?

`

```
class Solution:
    def canConstruct(self, ransomNote: str, magazine: str) -> bool:
        
        dict1 = {}
        for letter in magazine:
            
            if letter not in dict1:
                dict1[letter] = magazine.count(letter)
                
        
        for letter in ransomNote:
            
            if letter not in dict1 or dict1[letter] < ransomNote.count(letter):
                return "False"
            
        return "True"
```

`

This is an example of "OR" statement for an "if" inside a loop.

In my calculation it is coming up to: O(m^2 * d) + O(nd + n^2) (where n = size of ransomNote, m = size of magazine, and d = size of dictionary) but that can be grossly wrong.

I calculated it like below:

```
for letter in magazine: #O(m)
            
            if letter not in dict1: #O(d)
                dict1[letter] = magazine.count(letter) #O(m)
                
for letter in ransomNote: #O(n)
            
            if letter not in dict1 or dict1[letter] < ransomNote.count(letter): #O(d) + O(n)
                return "False"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you arrive at your "calculation"?

Comment: for letter in magazine: --O(m)
            
            if letter not in dict1: --O(d)
                dict1[letter] = magazine.count(letter) --O(m)
                
for letter in ransomNote: --O(n)
            
            if letter not in dict1 or dict1[letter] < ransomNote.count(letter): --O(d) + O(n)
                return "False"

Then adding the loops: O(m^2 * d) + O(nd + n^2)

Comment: [Continued]

Looks like I added "d" by mistake when it should have been multiplied. Turns out the initial calculation wasn't correct either. Am I still calculating it all wrong? I read that "in" operation in dictionary may have worst case as O(d) though it is very rare. 

I'm not sure how "OR" operator's complexity works but I think in worst case it will check for both conditions for the entire "for" loop?

Comment: Ah, this comment looks very messy. I will add my supposed calculation in the original question.